# Increase KSP tooltip text size?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

When playing in larger resolutions, UI elements become tiny in KSP. Luckily, with UI Scale and App Scale, things can be increased to a useable size.

However, the tooltips on orbits (e.g. for periapsis/apoapsis/distance informations) remain tiny. Even worse, the large cursor now obstructs most of the text and I often cannot read it.

Is there a way (config, mod) to increase these tooltip text sizes or to show them elsewhere?

[image: Screenshot with small text marked]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for a mod called 4KSP, which has been expanded on and updated to be compatible with the latest version of the game. (This is only possible on PC).
https://forum.kerbalspaceprogram.com/index.php?/topic/197794-18x-19x-110x-4ksp-expanded/

Comment: Awesome! I actually ended up writing my own little mod that showed distances in a large font, but this mod is really _exactly_ what I would've wanted.